# How to check if 5 random numbers are the same

Tags: c#, .net, random

I can't figure out how to test if 5 randomly generated numbers are the same.
All i have so far is the creation of them.

```
dice1 = rand.Next(1,7);

dice2 = rand.Next(1,7);

dice3 = rand.Next(1,7);

dice4 = rand.Next(1,7);

dice5 = rand.Next(1,7);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this to generate 5 random dice rolls:

```
var dice = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5) select rand.Next(1, 7)).ToArray();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var dice = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => rand.Next(1, 7)).ToArray();
```

And this to check their equality:

```
var first = dice.First(); // or dice[0];
var areSame = dice.Skip(1).All(d => d == first);
```

Comment: Beware lazy/deferred execution. `dice` might be reevaluated (generating a different first value) on your last line at the bottom, resulting in different values.

Comment: linq query should be executed only once at 1st usage, then reused

Comment: @TimS. Good point. I didn't think of that as a big issue but in this case it really is. I've added `ToArray()` to make it a bit more eager.

Comment: @Fabske Actually, that's not true, at least not in the general case. Try my code without the `ToArray()` and you will find that usually `dice.First() != dice.First()`.

Comment: indeed! Ty I've leaned a new thing!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3 && dice3 == dice4 && dice4 == dice5) {
  // scream at the random number generator
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited, brain fart on my first answer.

You can do some kind of nested if easily enough:

```
if ((dice1 == dice2)&&(dice2 == dice3)&&(dice3 == dice4)&&(dice4 == dice5))
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dice1 == dice2)
    if(dice2 == dice3)
        if(dice3 == dice4)
            if(dice4 == dice5)
                //do something...
```

might be a prettier way, but this will work

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new int[7];
result[dice1]++;
result[dice2]++;
result[dice3]++;
result[dice4]++;
result[dice5]++;
results.Any(x=>x==5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Throw them in a `HashSet` and then check that the sizes are the same

```
var dice = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => rand.Next(1, 7)).ToArray();
var set = new HashSet<int>(dice);
bool areSame = set.Count == 1; //1 unique value means they are all the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like this:

```
public static bool AllEqual(params int[] values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
        if (values[0] != value)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

And use it like:

```
bool allSame = AllEqual(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5);
```

But generating all of your dice in one enumerable element is probably better, as p.s.w.g showed.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest getting your dice into something enumerable. P.S.W.G. posted a really elegant way to do that and I'm kind of jealous I wouldn't have thought of it. This is where my mind went:

```
        var dice = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dice.Add(rand.Next(1, 7));
        }
```

Then you can use a simple evaluation to determine if all the numbers in the collection are the same. I like this:

```
        // if all the dice rolled the same, do something
        if (dice.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {

        }
```